# Hide sidebar and navbar in some states

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using the code below to hide the navbar and sidebar in my application template in the routes: `index.index`, `login.index`, `errors.404`, `errors.505` and errors.feature:

```
  hideNavbarAndSidebar: computed.equal('currentRouteName',
    'index.index',
    'login.index',
    'errors.404',
    'errors.505',
    'errors.feature'
  ),
```

The problem is: Doesn't work. Will only work in the first route, the `index.index`

How could i improve this code to make what i need??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ember.computed.equal](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.2.0/packages/ember-metal/lib/computed_macros.js#L261) only takes a single dependent key and a single value:

```
function equal(dependentKey, value)
```

If you want to compare to multiple values, you have to write your own computed property that depends on the `currentRouteName` and compares it to all of your values.

Here's one way how to do it in the latest Ember:

```
hideNavbarAndSidebar: Ember.computed('currentRouteName', function() {
    let route = this.get('currentRouteName');
    let routes =  ['index.index', 'login.index', 'errors.404', 'errors.505','errors.feature'];
    return routes.indexOf(route) !== -1;
})
```